# Javascript hide / show element and stop autoscroll

Tags: show-hide, autoscroll

Im using hide and show via javascript on DIV element.
But if I hide or show this element on page so my page everytime autoscroll to this element.

How can I stop this autoscroll on this element please?

Comment: Are you using plain JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: Its same if Im using $("#element").hide(); or If Im using via css $( "#element" ).addClass( "element_hide" );

Comment: Try `$("#element").style.display = 'none'`.

Comment: Its same I tried this. I have also style.display = 'none' in CSS

Comment: Did you try `document.getElementById('element').style.display = 'none'` as well?

Comment: Yes its same. :/

Comment: What third-party libraries are you using?

Comment: jquery, moment, daterangepicker

Comment: Temporarily disable all those libraries and try again. If that works, you can reenable them one by one to see which one is causing the problem.